# Laravel 5.3 keeps logging out

Tags: php, session, authentication, laravel-5, logout

I'm working on a new app with laravel 5.3(.18) and for some reason the session keeps getting lost. After logging in (even with remember token) I get logged out as soon as I go to any other location, and therefore redirected to the login page again.

I have the following in routes/web.php

```
Auth::routes();

Route::get('/', function () {
    if( Auth::guest() ){
        return view('auth.login');
    }else{
        return view('welcome');
    }
});

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function () {
    Route::resource('orders', 'OrderController');
    Route::resource('products', 'ProductController');
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'DashboardController@show');
});
```

I already switched the session to 'database' in my env file and migrated.

Any ideas?

Comment: Maybe it's not a problem in your app, but with your client, like blocking cookies.

Comment: @OlafDietsche tried on other browsers.. same thing..

Answer (score 0):

Anyone who still encountering this problem can check if they are using `Auth::logout()` in their views. Was the issue in my case.

Comment: That'd certainly do it, but is probably an unlikely explanation in most cases.